# Store return value of batch command to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I can run this line in a cmd prompt and get a single line back:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile "Get-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FeatureUsage\AppSwitched ^| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property ^| Where-Object { $_ -Match 'steamapps\\common\\Among Us\\Among Us.exe' }"
```

But how can I use this in a batch script? I tryed this and a few more things but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off 
set psScript=powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile "Get-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FeatureUsage\AppSwitched ^| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property ^| Where-Object { $_ -Match 'steamapps\\common\\Among Us\\Among Us.exe' }"

for /F "delims=" %L in (%psScript%) do (set "VAR=%%L")

echo %VAR%
```

Comment: two snytax errors in your `for` command: `for /f "delims=" %%L in ('%psScript%') do ...`

Comment: Ok I did that. With ' at `('%psScript%')` I get `ECHO is turned on` and without the ' at `(%psScript%)` I get `The file "powershell" cant be found`.

Comment: without the single quotes, `for` tries to process a filename. A command has to be enclosed in single quotes. You get `ECHO is ON` because the variable is empty (which means PowerShell doesn't return any output)

Comment: So any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe ```for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`%psScript%`) do …```, see https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: Neither of your pipe's, (`|`) require escaping, (with caret's, `^`), in PowerShell.

Comment: @JosefZ This will just print the command. @ Compo Yes, that did work! After removing the pipes I get the value I wanted :D

Comment: As well as the advice I've offered above, as per your earlier, now deleted, [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73856810), you actually wanted to locate the path of the executable. As the use of PowerShell is not needed for that, I have submitted an alternative answer which should achieve it too.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the location of your specific executable via that registry key from your batch file without having to use powershell.exe.

Display the application path:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
PushD "%SystemDrive%\"
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FeatureUsage\AppSwitched" /F "\Among Us.exe" /V 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"\\Among Us\.exe\>"') Do For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do Echo %%~fI
PopD
Pause
```

Save the application path as a variable:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
PushD "%SystemDrive%\"
Set "AppPath="
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FeatureUsage\AppSwitched" /F "\Among Us.exe" /V 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"\\Among Us\.exe\>"') Do For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do Set "AppPath=%%~fI"
PopD
If Defined AppPath (Echo %AppPath%& Pause)
```